# Am I doing functional programming when I define all of my functions in a class in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, functional-programming

I am asking this question because I don't want to humiliate myself in a job interview in near future.

I like to create many functions in one place when programming and avoid creating classes and dealing with entity states as much as possible. Can I say that I like functional programming and this is my style or preference in programming or do I have to use a functional programming language like F# or Haskell to be able to say that?

---

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms I am actually doing imperative programming in an object oriented language.

Comment: Probably a question for [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can do functional programming in an oop language. If I understand correctly, functional simply means that you pass in all the stuff the function needs and you take out again the results, storing nothing for next call etc. In other words, your classes and methods are stateless.

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain what the downvote is for? Seems like the answer was good to the OP..

Answer (score 5):

No.

The hallmarks of functional programming are

- avoiding objects (or anything else) with state changes
- avoiding mutable data and mutable data structures (more simply; variables don't change their values)
- all (or very nearly all) functions are [*pure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Many functional languages also rely on pattern matching and strong typing, though it is possible to program in a functional style in a language which lacks these features.

To learn more about functional programming, consider reading an introduction to the field (for example [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)).

Comment: although this question may look smart-alec, it is not intended to be: if variables don't change their values, then should we be calling them something other than _variables_ since this word "variable" means that by definition it is allowed to change?  So I ask this to help me get a little better understanding of functioanl programming.  TIA.

Comment: @philologon The term "variable" is used in functional programming in an older sense, coming from mathematics. In `f(x) = x + 1`, `x` is a variable because that equation should be valid when the function `f` is applied to *any* `x`, so you can imagine `x` varying over all possible values. Rebinding names or altering objects that exist at runtime are notions that don't even apply when you're thinking this mathematical sense.

Comment: @philologon "Variable" there is as opposed to a (possibly unknown) *constant*. In `f(x) = x + c`, `c` is probably a constant; I may not know what value it is, but it is standing in for one particular number. Whereas the `x` is a variable; it can take on any value.

Answer (score 4):

No. Putting all methods in one class makes you a fan of *procedural* programming, in other words, you are anti-OOP.

You could claim to be doing *functional* programming in C#, if most/all of your variables/arguments/functions were `const` or `readonly`, of if these qualifiers could be applied.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you describe is more procedural programming, not the functional one.